# Find a one parameter family of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, parameter-estimation, initial-value-problems

[image]

Im stuck on this problem. Am I suppose to get the anti-derivative function of the differential and then plug in the initial value?

Comment: @Moo y(0)=0 , at any point would I plug an equation into the differential?

Answer (score 2):

We are solving the differential equation.
$$xy'=y$$
$$\implies$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\implies$$
$$y=cx\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$$
We take the initial condition into account
$$0=0$$
Which is a tautology, satisfied by any $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the one parameter family of solutions satisfying the initial condition $y(0)=0$ is
$$y=cx\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$$

The thing to notice, if computation is to be avoided is that a free constant cannot be present in $y$, as the differentiation eliminates it, while multiplication with $x$ does not restore it. Further, one could inspect that if a polynomial is present in $y$, than differentiation would have lowered its order, but also multiply it with a constant (the order). Simply multiplying with $x$ does not undo these operations, unless the order of the polynomial is $1$. Therefore
$$y=cx\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$$
are the only possible solutions.